# MYSQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select users whom have the same city_id and country_id with the current user.

I intentionally allowed country and city to be independent because some flexibility reasons.

does is it look like something like this?

```
SELECT id, country_id, city_id, surname FROM users WHERE 
   country_id = (SELECT id,country_id FROM users WHERE id = 'current_user') AND 
   city_id = (SELECT id, city_id FROM users WHERE id = 'current_id')
```

any ideas pls?

Comment: You're on the right track - any more specific problems?

Comment: I was thinking there is a more professional, effective, faster and shorter approach.

Comment: @Diarmaid Are you sure he is? He selects two fields with a subquery used in "=" comparison. That's definitely not a right track ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT u2.id, u2.country_id, u2.city_id, u2.surname 
    FROM users u1
        INNER JOIN users u2
            ON u1.country_id = u2.country_id
                AND u1.city_id = u2.city_id
                AND u1.id <> u2.id
    WHERE u1.id = 'current_id'
```

Comment: +1 - using `JOIN`s should give better performance than subqueries.

Comment: Actually, @Piskvor, that's a myth. In circumstances where the subqueries return _different_ rowsets for each row of the primary query, that's often the case (such as `where childcolumn = parentquery.something`). But in the case where the subqueries don't change (such as this case where the current_id is constant), any decent DBMS should basically just run two blindingly fast queries (assuming `id` is indexed of course) followed by the main one. I know that DB2 does this. Not sure about other DBMS'.

Comment: @Piskvor, @paxdiablo: Out of curiousity, I tried both versions on Microsoft SQL Server on an Address table with just over 0.5M rows and, *if* city_id and country_id are indexed, then this join version outperforms the subquery version.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be objecting against including the user with `id = 'current_id'` into the output, so `AND u1.id <> u2.id` is probably unwarranted.

Comment: Thanks all. Actually AND u1.id <> u2.id is important as it prevents the 'current_id' from being included in the result.

Comment: Joins are easier for the sql parser to optimize, and should be used when possible.

Comment: @paxdiablo: You are right, I have overgeneralized; JOINs are definitely not The Answer To Life, Universe And Everything, and there are cases where subqueries are better. Anyway, the emphasis is on "should": I remember that I had problems with speed of a similar subquery in MySQL a while ago (haven't tried with 5.5 yet). As usual, whoever works on this should measure how it stacks up in their *specific* situation.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you shouldn't be selecting the `id` fields within the subqueries.

Instead, look into using something like:

```
SELECT id, country_id, city_id, surname
FROM users
WHERE country_id = (SELECT country_id FROM users WHERE id = 'current_id')
  AND city_id    = (SELECT city_id    FROM users WHERE id = 'current_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Frank,

```
.. WHERE country_id = (SELECT id,country_id FROM users ..
```

you are comparing a single value (**country_id**) to a two-column result set (**id**, **country_id**). This is wrong.

Your query, rewritten, would be:

```
SELECT id,country_id,city_id,surname FROM users WHERE country_id = (SELECT country_id FROM users WHERE id = 'current_user') AND city_id = (SELECT city_id FROM users WHERE id = 'current_id')
```